# Change public Transforms based on collision. Change line renderer points based on public transforms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, transform, mesh-collider

I'm pretty new and I can't seem to get this to work. Players have a long pole and if they poke certain objects it starts a string-like connection to the next one they poke. These objects are tagged as "PokableObjects", and to poke players will click. I'm going to have hundreds of different pokable objects, and I want the script on the pole to work for all of them.

I think I'm misunderstanding how to reference only the objects being poked. I want the points of a Bezier Curve script, which are public Transforms, to adapt and become whatever "PokableObject" the player clicks.

This is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    //curved line renderer stuff
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public Transform p0;
    public Transform p1;
    public Transform p2;

    //Object name detection stuff
    bool m_Started;
    public LayerMask m_LayerMask;

    //Respawn Stuff
    private float clickCounter;
    public GameObject newPoker;

    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        m_Started = true;
        clickCounter = 0;
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)

    {
        if (other.tag == "PokableObject")

        {
            Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(gameObject.transform.position, transform.localScale / 2, Quaternion.identity, m_LayerMask);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && (clickCounter == 0))
            {
                p0 = Collider.gameObject.position;
                clickCounter++;
            }
                
  
            else
            {
                p2 = Collider.gameObject.position;

                //find midpoint between p0 & p2 then lower it's Y coordinate by 1
                p1 = ((p0.position.x + p2.position.x) * .05f, ((p0.position.y + p2.position.y) * .05f) - 1), (p0.position.z + p2.position.z) * .05f;

                //disable current object and spawn a new one so players can repeat
                Instantiate(newPoker, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                GetComponent<BCurve>().enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(p0.position, p1.position, p2.position);

    }

    void DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2)

    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 200;
        float t = 0f;
        Vector3 B = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < lineRenderer.positionCount; i++)
        {
            B = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p0 + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p1 + t * t * p2;
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, B);
            t += (1 / (float)lineRenderer.positionCount);
        }
    }
}
```

All help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all **never** compare `float` values using `==`! Due to floating point (im)precision this might fail even though logically you think it would match.

  E.g.

  ```
   0.2f * 5f / 10f == 1.0f
  ```

  is **not** necessarily `true` because it might actually be `1.0000001` or `0.9999999`.

  This said anyway it makes no sense to use a `float` for a counter. You rather want to use

  ```
  int clickCounter;
  ```
- Then you have a bunch of `,` there when calculating `p1`. Seems like this should have been wrapped in a `p1 = new Vector3( .... )`
- However anyway the `p1` you calculate is no `Transform` but would rather be a `Vector3` position. You don't need this as a field! Simply recalculate it later given the two `Transform`s `p0` and `p2` within `DrawQuadraticBezierCurve` and then you can simply make it

  ```
  var p1 = (p0.position + p2.position) * .05f - Vector3.up;
  ```
- There is no need for that `LayerMask` and `OverlapBox` which result you are not using anywhere at all. You already have a tag to check your hit
- `Collider.gamObject` makes no sense. What you want is access the `Transform` of the object you are colliding with which simply is the `other.Transform`
- There is no need for `GetComponent<BCurve>`. This component already **is** the `BCurve` so you *could* simply use

  ```
  enabled = false;
  ```
- However, as soon as you get the second point you are disabling the component so `Update` will never be called again.

  Either you want to draw the line only once with the positions in that moment so simply call `DrawQuadraticBezierCurve` right away and remove your entire `Update` method.

  Or if your objects might continue moving and you want to continuously update the line then keep `Update` but keep this component enabled.
- In both cases you should only call `DrawQuadraticBezierCurve` once you already have both `Transform`s.

---

So all together it could look like this

```
public class BCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    //curved line renderer stuff
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    public Transform start;
    public Transform end;

    //Respawn Stuff
    public GameObject newPoker;

    // I would make this adjustable via the Inspctor
    [SerializeField] private int positionCount = 200;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(!lineRenderer) lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if(start && end)
        {
            return;
        }

        // in general rather use CompareTag instead of ==
        // the second silently fails in case of typos and is slightly slower
        if (other.CompareTag("PokableObject"))
        {
            // Then you ALWAYS want to check fr the mouse click, not only 
            // if the counter is 0
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                // you rather want to check here
                if (!start)
                {
                    start = other.transform;
                }
                // I would add a check though to not enable to click on the same object twice
                else if (other.transform != start)
                {
                    end = other.transform;

                    // If you anyway want the line to be drawn only ONCE with the current positions 
                    // then directly call this here and delete Update completely
                    //DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(start.position, end.position);
                    //enabled = false;
                    // or even
                    //Destroy(this);

                    Instantiate(newPoker, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(start && end)
        {
           DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(start.position, end.position);
        }
    }

    private void DrawQuadraticBezierCurve(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p2)
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = positionCount;
        var inversePositionCount = 1f / positionCount;
        var t = 0f;

        var p1 = (p0.position + p2.position) * .05f - Vector3.up;
        var positions = new Vector3[positionCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < lineRenderer.positionCount; i++)
        {
            var B = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p0 + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p1 + t * t * p2;
            positions[i] = B;
            t += inversePositionCount;
        }

        // Note: It is WAY cheaper to call this and set all positions at once
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this worked with a couple tweaks. I also learned a lot reading it, and your comments helped a lot. I definitely should and am going to add something to prevent payers from clicking the same object twice.

Answer (score 0):

derHugo gave an amazing answer, and could not have figured this out otherwise! I added a few things and it's working perfectly. The first thing was to make sure a new LineRender object is being created which a new poker object would automatically reference and have the start and end points be reset:

```
private void Start()
    {
        if (!lineRenderer) lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer = Instantiate(lineObject, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)).GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        start = null;
        end = null;
        destroy = false;
    }
```

The second was to move both the destruction of the current poker and the instantiation of a new poker to a LateUpdate, because the line wasn't being rendered:

```
private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (destroy == true)
        {
            Instantiate(newPoker, transform.position, transform.rotation).transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("MainCamera").transform);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Again, thank you for the help derHugo!